# WCF or ASP.net Webservice which uses Sap gateway for microsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, wcf, sap-gateway

I hope my question isn't too broad to answer: 
I am planing to create a webservice (either wcf or asp.net) to connect my  Windows Desktop Software to various datasources one of them is a sap database. Is using the SAP Gateway for Microsoft the best idea for this approach? I would include the SAP Datasources in my Webservice that means my desktop application would request data and my webservice decides where it can get the data from or where to it has to save the data (mssql database, as400, sap or whatever).

Comment: Yes, that's a great idea, or no, it isn't. What's the alternative and why would or wouldn't that suffice?

Comment: the question is if it is architectual a good idea? is that the right access method has somebody expericence with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SAP Gateway for Microsoft if you are consuming Odata service from an SAP Gateway system, I don't think it would be of much help in interfacing with different databases.